# delete listview item populated by SQlite using a Dialogfragment

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am new to Android programming and I have been stuck for 4 days trying to figure this one out.

App structure

1) Main activity  - Mainactivity contains the following features
    a) ListView which receives information from an SQLite database ("TASKDATABASE") and populates objects of  Class task
    b) Add icon in Action bar which links to a dialogfragment "CreateTask" - This creates a new task 
    c) TextView which captures the number of Tasks in Listview (ie number of listview items)
    d) Option to delete task by clicking on listview and calling another Dialogfragment "TaskOptions"

2) Class Task
3) Class TaskDatabase which adds a SQLite database called "TASKDATA"
4) DialogFragment CreateTask which links to add button in action bar of Mainactivity - This creates a new task
5) DialogFragment Taskoptions which is called on clicking an item from ListView in MainActivity

Issue - I am not able to delete item from ListView by calling DialogFragment Taskoptions ! No error messages. Item is not getting deleted ! Evrything else is working fine !

Here are the codes
**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.task;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CreateTask.CreateNewTask,TaskOptions.onDelete {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;
private ListView listView;
private TextView textView2;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SQLiteOpenHelper taskDatabase = new TaskDatabase(this);
    db = taskDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
    cursor = db.query("TASKDATA", new String[]{"_id", "TODAY"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor,
            new String[]{"TODAY"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
            0);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int y=(int)id;
            DialogFragment taskOptions = new TaskOptions();
            Bundle args=new Bundle();
            args.putInt("id",y);
            taskOptions.setArguments(args);
            taskOptions.show(getFragmentManager(),"");
        }
    };
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.create_new:
            CreateTask createTask = new CreateTask();
            createTask.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


@Override
public void createNewTask(Task task) {
    String task1 = task.getDescription();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("TODAY", task1);
    SQLiteOpenHelper taskDatabase = new TaskDatabase(this);
    db = taskDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert("TASKDATA", null, contentValues);
    cursor = db.query("TASKDATA", new String[]{"_id", "TODAY"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor,
            new String[]{"TODAY"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
            0);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));


}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
}

@Override
public void onDeleteItem(int m) {
    SQLiteOpenHelper taskDatabase = new TaskDatabase(this);
    db = taskDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete("TASKDATA", "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(m)});
    cursor = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).getCursor();

    CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor,
            new String[]{"TODAY"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
            0);
    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);**/
     textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     textView2.setText(String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));

    }




}
```

**DialogFragment - TaskOptions**

```
package com.example.todoo;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TaskOptions extends DialogFragment {
private int m ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_options,null);
    m=getArguments().getInt("num");
    ListView listView2 = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

    return v;
}
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener= new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position==1){
            MainActivity activity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
            activity.onDeleteItem(m);
            dismiss();
        }
    }
};
public interface onDelete {
    void onDeleteItem(int m);

}
```

}

```
package com.example.task;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TaskOptions extends DialogFragment {
private int m ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_options,null);
    m=getArguments().getInt("num");
    ListView listView2 = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    listView2.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

    return v;
}
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener= new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if(position==1){
            MainActivity activity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
            activity.onDeleteItem(m);
            dismiss();
        }
    }
};
public interface onDelete {
    void onDeleteItem(int m);

}
```

}

**Class TaskDatabase**

```
package com.example.task;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TaskDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final static String DB_NAME = "TASKDATA";
private final static int DB_VERSION = 1;

public TaskDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TASKDATA ( "
                 +"_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                   +"TODAY TEXT);");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}


}
```

DialogFragment CreateTask

```
package com.example.task;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class CreateTask extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}



@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_task, container, false);
    ImageButton imageButton=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        return view;
    }

private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String newTask = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
        Task task = new Task(newTask);
        task.setDescription(newTask);
        MainActivity activity1 = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        activity1.createNewTask(task);
        dismiss();
    }

};

public interface CreateNewTask{
     void createNewTask(Task task);

}
```

}

Pls let me know where I am going wrong !

Regards
AJ